# Reading timestamp from FIFO in LSM6DS3

Tags: sensor, imu

I using an LSM6DS3 sensor in order to estimate motion and derive.  For this purpose I am reading X,Y,Z acceleration values computing linear acceleration and using a time component to derive speed and displacement (end of loop - start of loop).  This was initially done in a polling loop, however I discovered that I am getting inconsistent results.  My thought is that I might be dropping values and so I decided to switch to reading values out of the FIFO buffer.

At this point I am able to once again read the X,Y,Z acceleration values, I can determine what I am currently reading by looking at the buffer pattern and the values are consistently 0, 1 and 2.  However I am now missing the time component.  I have attempted to enter the appropriate configuration to trigger pedometer + timestamp values to be also entered into a FIFO, but I m not able to verify the correctness of my programming.

My question is: if I have done everything correctly should I see another buffer pattern value (other then 0,1,2) to indicate that I am now reading pedometer + timestamp from FIFO?

P.S. I am purposefully leaving out my code and environment details as I do not think this is relevant, but can include it if anyone thinks it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my assumption was correct, after enabling **FUNC_EN** bit in **CTRL_10C**, and then **TIMER_EN** and **PEDO_EN** in **TAP_CFG**, I am seeing

Buffer pattern: 0
Buffer pattern: 1
Buffer pattern: 2
Buffer pattern: 4
Buffer pattern: 5

Unfortunately because of the pattern and data shift my readings are now off
abs(aX): 0.48 **abs(aY): 4.00** abs(aZ): 0.96,
As 4g on the Y axis is entirely incorrect for s stationary object (4g on any axis would be incorrect here)